# Can I override `$` or `[[` to throw an error instead of NULL when asking for a missing list element?

Tags: r, list, fail-fast

My hunch is this is an abuse of the `R` language and there's a good reason this doesn't happen. But I find this to be a perpetual source of insidious errors in code that I'm trying to debug:

MWE

```
list.1 <- list(a=1,b=2,c=list(d=3))
list.2 <- list(b=4,c=list(d=6,e=7))
input.values <- list(list.1,list.2)
do.something.to.a.list <- function(a.list) {
    a.list$b <- a.list$c$d + a.list$a
    a.list
}
experiment.results <- lapply(input.values,do.something.to.a.list)

use.results.in.some.other.mission.critical.way <- function(result) {
    result <- result^2
    patient.would.survive.operation <- mean(c(-5,result)) >= -5
    if(patient.would.survive.operation) {
        print("Congrats, the patient would survive! Good job developing a safe procedure.")
    } else {
        print("Sorry, the patient won't make it.")
    }
}

lapply(experiment.results, function(x) 

use.results.in.some.other.mission.critical.way(x$b))
```

**YES** I am aware this is a stupid example and that I could just add a check for the existence of the element before trying to access it. But I'm not asking to know what I *could* do, if I had perfect memory and awareness at all times, to work slowly around the fact that this feature is inconvenient and causes me lots of headache. I'm trying to avoid the headache altogether, perhaps at the cost of code speed.

So: what I want to know is...

(a) Is it possible to do this. My initial attempt failed, and I got stuck trying to read the `C` internals for "$" to understand how to handle the arguments correctly

(b) If so, is there a good reason not to (or to) do this.

Basically, my idea is that instead of writing every single function that depends on non-null return from list access to check really carefully, I can write just one function to check carefully and trust that the rest of the functions won't get called with unmet preconditions b/c the failed list access will fail-fast.

Comment: what about `'[[' <- function(x, i) if (is.null(res <- base::\`[[\`(x, i))) simpleError('NULL') else res` and use `mtcars[['asdf']]` you could overload the others the same way i expect

Comment: Right--good idea. I forgot I could just pass the arguments on to the `base::` version of the accessors. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override almost anything in R (except certain special values - `NULL`, `NA`, `NA_integer_` `NA_real_` `NA_complex_`, `NA_character_`, `NaN`, `Inf`, `TRUE`, `FALSE` as far as I'm aware).

For your specific case, you could do this:

```
`$` <- function(x, i) {
  if (is.list(x)) {
    i_ <- deparse(substitute(i))
    x_ <- deparse(substitute(x))
    if (i_ %in% names(x)) {
      eval(substitute(base::`$`(x, i)), envir = parent.frame())
    } else {
      stop(sprintf("\"%s\" not found in `%s`", i_, x_))
    }
  } else {
    eval(substitute(base::`$`(x, i)), envir = parent.frame())
  }
}

`[[` <- function(x, i) {
  if (is.list(x) && is.character(i)) {
    x_ <- deparse(substitute(x))
    if (i %in% names(x)) {
      base::`[[`(x, i)
    } else {
      stop(sprintf("\"%s\" not found in `%s`", i, x_))
    }
  } else {
    base::`[[`(x, i)
  }
}
```

Example:

```
x <- list(a = 1, b = 2)
x$a
#[1] 1
x$c
#Error in x$c : "c" not found in `x`
col1 <- "b"
col2 <- "d"
x[[col1]]
#[1] 2
x[[col2]]
#Error in x[[col2]] : "d" not found in `x`
```

It will slow your code down quite a bit:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(x$a, base::`$`(x, a), times = 1e4)
#Unit: microseconds
#            expr    min     lq     mean median      uq      max neval
#             x$a 77.152 81.398 90.25542 82.814 85.2915 7161.956 10000
# base::`$`(x, a)  9.910 11.326 12.89522 12.033 12.3880 4042.646 10000
```

I've limited this to `list`s (which will include `data.frame`s) and have implemented selection with `[[` by numeric and character vectors, but this may not fully represent the ways in which `$` and `[[` can be used.

Note for `[[` you could use @rawr's simpler code:

```
`[[` <- function(x, i) if (is.null(res <- base::`[[`(x, i))) simpleError('NULL') else res
```

but this will throw an error for a member of a list which is `NULL` rather than just not defined. e.g.

```
x <- list(a = NULL, b = 2)
x[["a"]]
```

This may of course be what is desired.

Comment: `?reserved` are the other ones which cannot be overridded

Comment: This looks good--thanks. I wonder if any naysayers want to contribute a reason not to do this? I'm fine with the time cost your benchmarks indicate.

Comment: @rawr I've added `NULL` and the variants of `NA` to the answer. For the flow commands `if` etc., you can (if feeling particularly masochistic) override them. For example, try: `'for' <- function(var, seq, expr) sprintf(expr, seq); for (i in 1:10) "%d potatoes"`